# Which refracted rays are relevant?

Tags: game-physics, raytracing

Let's say I have a sphere. A ray hits the sphere, it refracts and enters inside, then it
hits the sphere again, this time from the inside. Do I take this color? Or should I ignore this color
and refract again, exit the sphere and collect color from the environment? In other words I just take
into account the color from the second refracted ray, the one that exits the sphere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the material composition. How much is the ray extinguished by passing through the material? The two most common ways to decide how far to trace are to either limit the # of bounces and refractions to an absolute #, or to keep track of the maximum amount of contribution at each step -- if it falls below, say, 0.5% of the expected display range, there's a good chance that it's safe to stop the chain of rays. Or you just hit a fully-opaque surface, or empty space.